# dynamically clip the image based on the size of the page in phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

I'am currently trying to generate the thumbnails for the urls using phantomjs. But for some of the urls it is not generating the image properly.
My test code is like this:

```
var webpage = require('webpage');

page = webpage.create();

page.viewportSize = {width: 15,
              height: 45};
page.zoomFactor = 0.30;

page.open('http://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20160504-openssl?vs_f=Cisco%20Security%20Advisory&vs_cat=Security%20Intelligence&vs_type=RSS&vs_p=Multiple%20Vulnerabilities%20in%20OpenSSL%20Affecting%20Cisco%20Products:%20May%202016&vs_k=1', function(status) {
    console.log(status);

    page.clipRect = { left:0, top:0, width:295, height: 200};

    page.render('d:/test/github.png');

    //console.log(render);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

for this particular url screenshot is not as same as i expected. half of the image is blank to the right side and to the left side image contents are coming.
But in most of the cases screenshot is properly coming.What is causing this issue i'am not figure out. i spent almost 3 to 4 hours on this already. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is PhantomJS version? Are there any errors? (use `page.onError` callback to find out)

Comment: @Vaviloff TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$("span.lockIcon img")'). This is the error it is showing.I'am using 2.1.1 version of phantomjs